# Update column with incremental date based on id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have table T1:

```
Id    Invoice    Date
1     A100
2     B100
```

I want to update table T1 with incremental date based on ID

Desired result:

```
Id    Invoice    Date
1     A100       GetDate()
2     B100       GetDate()+1
```

Is there something available like this:

```
update T1
set [Date]= GetDate() + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id)
from T1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a similar, but more direct approach as Larnu, you can update a CTE directly:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  *
    ,       ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn
    FROM    T1
)

UPDATE cte
    SET [date] = DATEADD(DAY, rn, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I was thinking of the same query. CTE is just like view. We can update a CTE as we can update view.

Comment: I find it interesting that your got an upvote, while mine a downvote. I think this really does suggest that the vote was a revenge vote (due to a comment i made pointing out that the statement would generate an error), a real shame (speaks volumes of the community at times)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?  update the date column based on id

```
    update T1
    set [Date]= GetDate() + (id-1)
    from T1
```

Comment: This trust that `ID` won't have any gaps. Never trust an `IDENTITY` column to not have gaps.

Comment: I over simplified it. I'm looking something with Row_Number()

Comment: It's also, generally, bad practice to use the format `{Date Expression/Value} + {Numerical Expression/Value}`. This works on `datetime` but it's recommend you use `datetime2`, `date` and `time` now, and that format won't work with those./

Answer (score 1):

use  `dateadd`

```
    update T2     
    SET  T2.D=dateadd(dd,T3.rn,getdate())
      FROM 
      T1 as t2 INNER JOIN 
      (
      select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [id]) as rn from T1
      ) T3 ON t2.id=t3.id
```

Comment: @Larnu yes its needs a subquery

Comment: @MYGz i changed answer it should have to work i checked

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin yes, i removed my comment, and downvote, as soon as you changed your answer, as the syntax error will no longer exist. If a issue with an answer (such as creating a syntax error) is resovled, then provided I notice (or are notified) i'll remove the comments/downvote, as they're no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use a CTE to evaluate the new dates with `ROW_NUMBER` and `DATEADD` and then `UPDATE` using the values from the CTE:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID int IDENTITY, SomeDate date)
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (SomeDate)
VALUES (GETDATE()),(GETDATE()),(GETDATE()),(GETDATE()),(GETDATE());
GO

SELECT *
FROM TestTable;
GO
WITH NewDates AS(
    SELECT ID, DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TT.ID), GETDATE()) AS NewDate
    FROM dbo.TestTable TT)
UPDATE TT
SET SomeDate = ND.NewDate
FROM dbo.TestTable TT
     JOIN NewDates ND ON TT.ID = ND.ID;
GO
SELECT *
FROM TestTable;

GO
DROP TABLE TestTable;
GO
```

Comment: I'd love the hear feedback on the downvote here, please. Really unsure why. This meets the OP's requirements of using `ROW_NUMBER` and you can easily copy this to test. I hope that the vote isn't a "revenge" vote, because of my comments on an answer they would generate a syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

Use `recursive cte` to generate `Id` and `dates` and then `join` your table based on `Id` column to update the dates

```
with cte as ( 
  select 1 AS Id, getdate() as dt
  union all
  select cte.Id+1, dateadd(d,1,cte.dt) 
  from   cte 
  where  cte.Id < (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM T1)
)
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Date = cte.dt
FROM T1 INNER JOIN cte ON T1.Id = cte.Id
```

Comment: An `IDENTITY` column doesn't have to start at 1, if you start with `SELECT MIN(ID) FROM T1` instead of `1`, it would be less overkill.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use `Windowed functions` directly in update query. you should store logic in some `temporary table` and then use that value in your update query. One way could be like below.

```
 ;with cte as
    (
     select id,Invoice,dateadd(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id), GetDate()) as dt
    from T1
    )
    update a
    set a.[date]= cte.dt
    from T1  a join cte on cte.id=a.id
    where a.id=cte.id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.